# Route not rendering even when window URL is changed

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I navigate to the same route twice even though the URL is changed,  the components are not re-rendered.

For example:

1. Navigate  to /dashboard/   this works
2. click a link to  /dashboard/project/1  this works
3. click a link that brings you to /dashboard/project/2 from step 2.  Then the url changes but the components are not re-rendered

If I refresh the page then it works but I don't want to refresh each time I navigate to /dashboard/project/:project

```
class Dashboards extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dashboards-root">
        <h1>Dashboards</h1>
        <Route exact path={this.props.match.url} component={ProjectWorkbookSplit} />
        <Route exact path={this.props.match.url + "/projects/:projectId/"} component={ProjectWorkbookSplit}/>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={ props => <ProjectWorkbookSplit propName={this.props.match.url} />} />

<Route exact path="/your_path" render={props => <ProjectWorkbookSplit your_prop_name={this.props.match.url} />} />
```

Components are only rendered if their state or props changes, so make sure the props that are passed to the components change so as to enforce re-rendering